# How to compare a sum of expressions with integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am learning Ruby and faced with some problem.I tried to compare a sum of expressions with integer and get this return: "comparison of String with 2000 failed". Thanks a lot!

```
puts "Hello! Please type here your birthday date."

puts "Day"
day = gets.chomp
day.capitalize!

puts "Month"
month = gets.chomp
month.capitalize!

puts "Year"
year = gets.chomp
year.capitalize!

if month + day + year > 2000
    puts "Sum of all the numbers from your birthday date is more than 2000"
else month + day + year < 2000
    puts "Sum of all the numbers from your birthday date is less than 2000"
end
```

Comment: Capitalize integers? Why?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev: they get bigger :)

Comment: Sure, reinvestment ;)

Comment: 674.capitalize => DCLXXIV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
day = gets.chomp
```

Here `day` is a string. And `month + day + year` is a string too, only longer. To get integers, call `.to_i`.

```
day = gets.to_i # to_i will handle the newline, no need to chomp. 
                # repeat for month and year
```

(*Of course, once you converted strings to integers, you won't be able to capitalize them. It made no sense anyway.*)

Comment: It works! Thank you! It seems like I didn't read up to this point.